# Populating standard name field with a case number

Tags: apex, custom-field, standardcontroller, inputfield

I am trying to populate the standard name field of an object with the case number. I have tried to use an apex class to accomplish this. Here is the code I used:

```
GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__c Volunteer_Job = new GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__c(
    GW_Volunteers__Campaign__c = lead.Campaign__c,
    Location__c = lead.Location__c,
    Total_Hours_Due__c = lead.Total_Hours_Due__c,
    Number_of_Hours_Due_Per_Week__c = lead.Number_of_Hours_Due_Per_Week__c,
    GW_Volunteers__Skills_Needed__c = lead.Skills_Needed__c,
    Case_Number__c = newCase.Id,
    Primary_Point_of_Contact__c = contact.Id,
    Name= case.Casenumber
);
insert Volunteer_Job;
```

and I receive this error:

```
Error   Error: Compile Error: Invalid initial expression type for field GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__c.Name, expecting: String at line 166 column 19
```

I believe this issue is occurring because `Name` is a text field and `Casenumber` is a lookup field.
I even tried to create a formula field set as text that associates with the Casenumber; however, I receive the same error when trying to map the field to `Name`

[image]

Comment: Just FYI, it's usually a good idea to name your variables different names than the objects to avoid additional confusion that can come up at run time.  **lead -> aLead**, **contact -> aContact**, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a nice solution to this. I set the last line to `Name='ChangetoCaseNumber'` and then made a workflow that is triggered after a volunteer job with `'ChangetoCaseNumber'` in the Name field is created. The workflow is what changes the text in the Name field to the case number. In a nutshell you would to go `Setup >> App Setup >> Create >> Workflow & Approvals >> Field Updates`. Create a new Field Update and populate the required fields.

Answer (score 2):

CaseNumber is a number type, not a string type.  You'll need to convert it to a String before you assign it to a String field.

Try the following instead:

```
Name= case.CaseNumber != null ?  String.valueOf(case.CaseNumber) : null;
```

Comment: The code you provided actually writes the word "CaseNumber" instead of putting the actual number of their case as the name.

Comment: @McCormick32 If `newCase` is the reference to your new Case object then it should be that `newCase.CaseNumber` not `case.CaseNumber` (which evaluates to the SObjectField type for that Case SObjectType field).

Comment: I have tried to use newCase.CaseNumber and it gives me a random mix of numbers and letters, not the case number.

Comment: Sure you aren't looking for newCase.Name instead?

Comment: There is not field named Name under case. I tried anyway and got this Error `Error: Compile Error: Invalid field Name for SObject Case at line 166 column 58`